# null space of an upper triangle Matrix

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I am trying to find the null space (basis for the Kernel) of an any given matrix in Java.To make life easier I am using ApacheMath's QR decomposition such that A=QR, where Q is Invertable (by itself) and R is an upper triangle Matrix.

which method should I use from ApacheMath's QR decomposition in order to calculate the basis for the Kernel of R (which is a basis for the kernel of A as well)?

I used :
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html

and

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/linear/QRDecomposition.html

references and came to the following code :

```
            RealMatrix coefficients =
                new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][] { { 1,2,2,3 }, { 2,4,1,3 }, { 3,6,1,4 } },
                                   false);
            DecompositionSolver solver = new QRDecomposition(coefficients).getSolver();




            RealVector constants = new ArrayRealVector(new double[] { 0,0,0 }, false);
            RealVector solution = solver.solve(constants);
```

and it sends an error that the matrix is singular which make sense because in the first reference that I use it says that:

"if the matrix is singular within the tolerance set at construction, an error will be triggered when the solve method will be called, both for algorithms that compute exact solutions and for algorithms that compute least square solutions.".

Comment: Does the documentation for ApacheMath not cover its API in a way that lets you find that out by reading through the various functions that are associated with matrix decomposition?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I looked in the API but I did not found the information I was looking for...

Comment: It is usually [a good idea](/help/how-to-ask) to tell people what you've already looked for, and where, and how that didn't address your need, so that people won't have to ask you to do those things.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I edited the post as best as I can that It will be very clear where I looked for. I also added a code .